# Loops: counting down until all digits in a number are odd

Tags: c, loops

I'm writing a c program that reads an entered number and counts down from that number until all the digits in a number are odd. So if 22 is input, the output would be: 22, 21, 20, 19. The program then needs to find the average of those numbers. The issue is I don't know how to break down the entered number into individual digits to identify if they're even or odd. This is what I have started:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int num, sum;
    double avg;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (num % 2 == 0) {
        printf("%d ", num);
        --num;
        printf("%d ", num);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

After I wrote this I realized it can only tell if the entered number is even or odd, not the individual digits.

Comment: Maybe converting the string to a number wasn't the right place to start :-) But, honestly, "counting down" is not the way to solve this problem. If you're doing this for some programming competition, it's a sure TLE.

Comment: ejcar, Break the problem into pieces.  Form a function `int is_all_odd_digits(int x);` and use `%10` to isolate the least digit and `/10` to reduce the remaining `x`.

Comment: And once that method of iterating over the digits in a number is mastered, finding the average of them should be trivial.

Comment: Suggestion: write a function to determine if the end condition has been reached (with `/10` and `%10`) and use it in your while condition: `while (hasevendigits(num)) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Yeah - enter it as a string or, if you cannot avoid an int entry, stringify it with sprintf().

Answer (score 0):

You should be using %10 and /10 here's an exemple : you analyse 15 your program will 15 % 10 -> 5 is it an odd number yes / no and then 15 / 10 -> 1 is it an odd number yes or no it's all you need !